# Google Partners - Adding to html

Tags: html, google-chrome, iframe

The company I work for just got the Google Partners Badge and they have asked me to add it to the main website as one of the logos, both in the navbar and in the footer.

However, they just sent me a link and not the logo in itself. So I was wondering what the best option to add this badge is.

Should I do an `<iframe src="www.loremipsum.com/partner.html">` or should I ask for or look for an img of the badge and link it to the Google Partners website such a `<a href="whttps://www.google.com/partners/mycompany"><img src="images/loremipsum.png"></a>`

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this code:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
<div class="g-partnersbadge" data-agency-id="XXXXXXXXXX"></div>
```

Comment: It does work, thank you very much. You can add that sanippet inside of a '<div>' or a '<p>' in order to style it and place it wherever you want.

Comment: Please do not wrap with a <p> tag.  Between, the two, I would go with the non-semantic <div> element. "The HTML <p> element represents a paragraph of text." https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element